# How to update dependency to existing ImageMagick

Tags: ubuntu, imagemagick, dcm4che, mogrify

`ImageMagick 6.8.9-9 Q16 x86_64 2018-09-28` is already installed on Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS Xenial. Was trying to convert jp2 to jpg but i got the below error

`mogrify: no decode delegate for this image format 'JP2' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/501.`

I followed few articles and they said `jp2` file support is missing so i installed successfully using command `sudo apt-get install libopenjp2-7-dev`.

When i do `identify -version` it does not show jp2 under delegates :

`Delegates: bzlib cairo djvu fftw fontconfig freetype jbig jng jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr pangocairo png rsvg tiff wmf x xml zlib`

Could anyone please help me how to include into existing ImageMagick

1. List item

Comment: You need OpenJPEG 2.1 or higher. What version did you install? I am not an expert on installing on Linux. But often you need to reinstall ImageMagick after installing a new delegate. But some one more expert on Linux may have a way to avoid that.

Comment: I installed openjpeg2.1 as well but the problem is its not getting updated with existing imagemagick delegates. I too tried to install new imagemagick version 6.9.10-14 but this also failed 2 tests out of 76 when running `make check`.

Comment: Sorry, but I know little about installing on Linux. But you could post your issue at https://imagemagick.org/discourse-server/ in the Developers forum. I am not sure that failing two tests is necessarily bad. So did you check to see if your Delegates now lists jp2 from `convert -version`. If not check the config.log file when installing openjpeg and imagemagick to see what might have gone wrong with the install. Perhaps openjpeg needs other supporting delegates

Answer (score 2):

Same problem, mind-blowing to distribute w/o jp2 support. Not aware of any way to add this after installation (since it's compiled in), but did solve the problem with a new install:

```
sudo apt purge imagemagick
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt install libopenjp2-7 libopenjp2-7-dev libopenjp2-tools opencl-headers
```

Then cd to desired parent dir and:

```
wget https://imagemagick.org/download/ImageMagick.tar.gz
tar xvzf ImageMagick.tar.gz
```

CD to newly created dir and, as normal:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Followed by:

```
sudo ldconfig /usr/local/lib
```

IM will try to install jp2 support by default so no need to add a configure option.

Lastly, IM's  [reference page](https://imagemagick.org/script/install-source.php#unix) notes that a modules build is recommended for advanced users. At the configure step, do instead:

```
./configure --with-modules --enable-shared --with-perl
```

PS. My config line, FWIW:

```
./configure --with-modules --enable-shared --with-perl --with-gslib --with-rsvg
```

Comment: I've made it `sudo apt install -y libjpeg62-dev libopenjp2-7 libopenjp2-7-dev libopenjp2-tools`

Comment: Thanks @JanMadeyski, just installed fresh in 18.04 machine and found one regex reference no longer interpreted. Also, it wants opencl-headers package preinstalled ("configure: WARNING: no OpenCL headers found"). So answer updated to current.

Comment: Make sure that `pkg-config` is installed prior to running `configure`.